# Upgrade to O365 broke EWS Autodiscover

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

My company just moved some mailboxes into O365. This has had the unfortunate effect of breaking an application created using EWS. When attempting to call out to AutodiscoverUrl(), I am met with an error.

> 'The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.'

Code:

```
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(mailbox, RedirectionCallback);

        private bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
        {
            return true; 
        }
```

I have also tried setting the URL to the following

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://autodiscover.MYDOMAIN.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml");
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

Neither of those have resolved the issue. Does anyone know where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- service.UseDefaultCredentials should be false because you need email+password(as secure string) for connect
- use latest ExchangeVersion value
- url is https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

  ```
  public ExchangeService Connect()
  {
      var lastExchangeVersion = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExchangeVersion)).Cast<ExchangeVersion>().ToList().Last();
      var service = new ExchangeService(lastExchangeVersion)
      {
          Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
          Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_cloudEmail, _cloudPassword)
      };
      return service;
  }
  public SecureString ConvertStringToSecure(string password)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return null;
      var result = new SecureString();
      foreach (char c in password) result.AppendChar(c);
      return result;
  }
  ```